# ffmpeg / avconv follow_mouse not working?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screencast

I'm trying the option `-follow_mouse` with both `ffmpeg` and `avconv` and I can't make it work.

`avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2` tells me:

`Option follow_mouse not found.`

`ffmpeg version git-2013-01-05-6717d1a`, doesn't complain, but the outline doesn't follow the mouse, and the resulting video is also not moving.

My full command line is the following:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -show_region 1 -r 10 -s 960x540 -i :0.0+10,200 \
    -acodec pcm_s16le -qscale 0 -follow_mouse 100 screencast.avi
```

How to make it work? Am I doing something wrong, or should I get a different version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Option placement](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) matters. [`-follow_mouse`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-6) is an input option, but you're attempting to apply it to the output, so ffmpeg will ignore it. Try:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -show_region 1 -follow_mouse 100 -r 10 \
-s 960x540 -i :0.0+10,200 -acodec pcm_s16le -qscale 0 screencast.avi
```